# Update column based on if a join exists - SQLITE

Tags: join, sqlite, sql-update

I can't seem to get this working in SQLITE.

I'm trying to add a 1 if a matching join exists for a row or a 0 if not.

I thought the code would add a 1 to those matching rows but instead it just adds a 1 to everything irregardless of a match:

```
update tbl1
SET has_data = 1
where exists(
    SELECT *
    FROM tbl1
    join tbl2 on tbl2.r_num = tbl1.r_num
)
```

I've seen some examples of 'case's that I couldn't figure how to write either that may be useful in this situation for applying a 0 or 1?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tbl1` in the subquery is an independent instance of the table, so the EXISTS is true if there is *some* row *anywhere* in `tbl1` that matches.

To refer to the original table, just don't introduce another table instance:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET has_data = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM tbl2
              WHERE r_num = tbl1.r_num);
```

Alternatively, this can be written as:

```
UPDATE tbl1
SET has_data = 1
WHERE r_num IN (SELECT r_num
                FROM tbl2);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that explanation.